# Remove committed files from commit

Tags: git, github

I accidentaly committed some very large PDF files that were well over GitHub's size limit, so when I later pushed, I got an error, and wasn't able to push. Now, I want to remove those files from the commit, without losing them locally, so that I can later add .pdf in `.gitignore` and commit and push my other changes. Does anyone know how I can do this?

I do not want to undo any changes, or risk to do that.

Comment: Have you looked at [How do you undo the last commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-you-undo-the-last-commit)

Comment: `git reset --soft HEAD~1` to undo the last commit.

Answer (score 9):

## Backup these files first

Open **terminal**, `cd` to your git directory and

```
git log
```

You will see something like this:

[image]

Then copy the **commit hash** before the addition of these large pdf files
and run this command

```
git reset --soft <good commit hash>
```

now you can push your local changes

Comment: But the (unreachable)blobs would still be there, right? Should OP run "git gc --aggressive" too or is this something that is taken care of when git push is done?

Answer (score 9):

You can try this:

```
git rm *.pdf
git commit --amend
```

I think this should fix your commit locally and then you can push it.

**EDIT**

*Copy* your PDFs to another location as the `rm` command will delete them from the git directory.

Comment: git rm *.pdf
zsh: no matches found: *.pdf

Any idea why I get this?

Comment: Are the PDFs still in the git directory?

Comment: I'm not sure why it isn't working. If they are currently in the latest git version  and branch `git rm *.pdf` should work (verified on my system even with the PDFs removed from the directory). Have you perhaps already removed them/reset the commit?